# Why the init() is called when the wifi is turned off and on

Tags: swift, firebase, swiftui, firebase-authentication, wifi

When I turn the wifi on and off the mainChatView init is called again but not the landingView init. Why?

So when the wifi is toggled in the console it is printed main chat init again

this is the code of the landingView:

```
struct LandingView: View {
    @State private var selection:Int = 2
    @State var connected: Bool = true
    @State var supposeToBeConnected: Bool = true
    @StateObject var networkReachability = NetworkReachability()
    var timer = Timer()
    init(){
        print("landing page init")
    }
    var body: some View {
        if connected {
            content
        }else{
            connectingView()
         }
    }
    var content: some View {
        ZStack{
        VStack{
        TabView(){
            MainChatView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "message")
                }
            HomeView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "house.fill")
                }
            yourGroups()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "rectangle.3.group.fill")
                }
            AccontView()
                .tabItem {
                    Image(systemName: "person.fill")
                }
            
        }
        .padding(.all, -2.0)
        .onAppear() {
            UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = .black
            Auth.auth().addStateDidChangeListener { auth, user in
                if let user = user {
                    if user != nil {
                        self.connected = true
                        self.supposeToBeConnected = true
                    }else{
                        self.supposeToBeConnected = false
                        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1) {
                            if !supposeToBeConnected{
                                print("cont changed")
                                self.connected = false
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            OnligneStatus()
            Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 60, repeats: true, block: { _ in
                    OnligneStatus()
                })
        }
        .statusBar(hidden: true)
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
    }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity,alignment: .top)
        .ignoresSafeArea(.all)
        .padding(.all, -1.0)
       

    }
    }
    func OnligneStatus(){
        print("online")
        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        if Auth.auth().currentUser != nil{
            db.collection("users").document(Auth.auth().currentUser!.uid).updateData([
                "onLine":Date()])
            }
    }
}
```

And this is the init:

```
init(){
    print("main chat init")
}
```

Thanks for helping me this bug caused image loading errors and text loading bugs

Comment: SwiftUI views are ephemeral descriptions of the view hierarchy at a point in time. They’re created in response to changes in state, and are not persisted the way you’re expected them to be. This is a common misconception (especially coming from UIKit, where UIView objects *was* persistent. Check out the introductory videos from WWDC, they nail this point home very well

Comment: Okay, but what in the code do I have to change to make it work well??

Comment: It depends on why you're trying to use the initializer for in the first place. Odds are, you probably need a completely different approach, but it's hard to say without knowing what you're trying to achieve. In any case, I would start by watching through https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2021/10022/ and https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2019/226/ to get a grasp of a the fundamentals here